# SQL Server batch and select statement output difference in decimal point

Tags: sql-server

Following batch statement if i execute in SSMS giving me Result like given below

```
DECLARE @M_TUBE_VOLUME NUMERIC(38,10),
@M_TUBE_OD NUMERIC(38,10)=12.50000,
@M_TUBE_ID NUMERIC(38,10)=12.50000,
@M_TUBE_LEN NUMERIC(38,10)=4000.00000,
@M_TUBE_COUNT NUMERIC(38,10)=212.4215000,
@M_S_TUBE_LEN NUMERIC(38,10)=0.0000,
@M_S_TUBE_COUNT NUMERIC(38,10)=3587.000

SET @M_TUBE_VOLUME=(SELECT 3.141592 / 4 * @M_TUBE_OD * @M_TUBE_ID * ((@M_TUBE_LEN * @M_TUBE_COUNT) + (@M_S_TUBE_LEN * @M_S_TUBE_COUNT)));

SELECT @M_TUBE_VOLUME

RESULT -- 104272138.7104680000
```

and if i execute same thing in SSMS using select statement

```
SELECT 3.141592 / 4 * 12.50000 * 12.50000 * ((4000.00000 * 212.4215000) + (0.0000 * 3587.000))

RESULT -- 104272138.285625000000000000000
```

Why two result are different any reason please help me

Answer (score 1):

it has something to do with rounding. As your computation involved numbers with decimal places.

Please refer to documentation [Precision, scale, and Length (Transact-SQL)](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/precision-scale-and-length-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)

I have extracted the relevant portion here

> ```
> Operation  Result precision                        Result scale *
> e1 * e2    p1 + p2 + 1                             s1 + s2
> e1 / e2    p1 - s1 + s2 + max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)      max(6, s1 + p2 + 1)
> ```
>
> - The result precision and scale have an absolute maximum of 38. **When a result precision is greater than 38, it's reduced to 38, and the
>     corresponding scale is reduced to try to prevent truncating the
>     integral part of a result**. In some cases such as multiplication or
>     division, scale factor won't be reduced, to maintain decimal
>     precision, although the overflow error can be raised.

In your second query, numbers like `3.141592` is taking as `numeric(7,6)` and `12.50000` is `numeric(7,5)` and in your first query, all those are `numeric(38,10)`

The rounding occurs on the first 4 expression.

I use `SELECT INTO` a temp table and then query the data type of the column in the temp table

```
SELECT  f1 = 3.141592 / 4 * @M_TUBE_OD * @M_TUBE_OD, 
        f2 = 3.141592 / 4 * 12.50000 * 12.50000
INTO    #t

select  c.name, t.name, c.precision, c.scale
from    tempdb.sys.columns c
        inner join master.sys.systypes t    on  c.system_type_id    = t.xtype
where   object_id   = object_id('tempdb..#t')

name  name      percision   scale
f1    numeric   38           6
f2    numeric   25          18
```

You can see that for your first query, the result `scale` is reduced to only `6`. So for first query, the result of the first 4 expression is `122.718438` (rounded to `38`) rather than `122.7184375`.

You over define the `precision` of your `numeric`. Reduce it and try

Comment: actually i am migrating oracle stored procedure into sql server there i am facing lot of problem of decimal.  In oracle we use number data type and in sql server which suitable data type can i use to get same result of oracle Please help because in many cases i am facing decimal mismatch problem

Comment: reduced the `precision` and try

Answer (score 0):

In the second version, you haven't explicitly defined your data type and it has defaulted to FLOAT.

You can verify this by changing your query to

```
DECLARE @M_TUBE_VOLUME FLOAT,
@M_TUBE_OD FLOAT=12.50000,
@M_TUBE_ID FLOAT=12.50000,
@M_TUBE_LEN FLOAT=4000.00000,
@M_TUBE_COUNT FLOAT=212.4215000,
@M_S_TUBE_LEN FLOAT=0.0000,
@M_S_TUBE_COUNT FLOAT=3587.000

SET @M_TUBE_VOLUME=(SELECT 3.141592 / 4 * @M_TUBE_OD * @M_TUBE_ID * ((@M_TUBE_LEN * @M_TUBE_COUNT) + (@M_S_TUBE_LEN * @M_S_TUBE_COUNT)));

SELECT @M_TUBE_VOLUME
```

Comment: `defaulted to FLOAT.` can you kindly provide the documentation reference on this ?

Comment: The data type precedence [link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/data-types/data-type-precedence-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15)  shows float with a higher precedence thandecimal. Therfore if you do not specify then it will use the highest suitable type

Comment: and one more thing i want to ask you instead of select if i use print then why showing difference

Comment: It doesn't default to `float`. You can see this from `SELECT thing, 
       sql_variant_property(thing,'basetype') AS basetype,
       sql_variant_property(thing,'precision') AS precision, 
       sql_variant_property(thing,'scale') AS scale, 
       sql_variant_property(thing,'maxlength') AS maxlength
FROM (values(3.141592 / 4 * 12.50000 * 12.50000 * ((4000.00000 * 212.4215000) + (0.0000 * 3587.000)))) v(thing)`